# Ember.js - How to resolve a computed property on a child before the child route is activated

Tags: ember.js

I have a Parent-Child-Grandchild relationship that looks like this:

```
Course
    - has_many Questions

Question
    - has_many Answers

Answer
```

On my Question model I have a computed property `answerCount`. When I get to the questions route `/courses/1/questions` the computed property is evaluated, but not before when I'm in the course route `/courses/1`.

I want to show users the number of unanswered questions when they enter the course route. But I'm only able to do it at the questions route because that is when the async has_many answers relationship resolves.

How can I get information about the `questions has_many answers` relationship before the relationship resolves? Or, how can I force the relationship to resolve in the parent route `/courses/1`?

Please let me know what additional information I can provide.

**EDIT 1**

I'm using kingpin2k's suggestion, but still not getting a resolved property. Here is the relevant code:

> Course Route

```
model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('course', params.course_id);
},
afterModel: function(model, transition) {
    // assuming questions are async
      return model.get('questions').then(function(questions){
        return Ember.RSVP.all(questions.getEach('answers'));
      });
},
setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', model)
},
```

> Course Controller

```
unansweredQuestions: function() {
    var self = this;
    var questions = this.get("course.questions");

    return questions.reduce(function(previousValue, question) {
      if (question.get("answerCount") > 0) {
        return previousValue;
      } else {
        return previousValue + 1;
      };
    }, 0)
}.property('course.questions.@each.answerCount'),
```

> Question Model

```
answerCount: function() {
    return this.get('answers').get('length')
}.property('answers.@each'),
```

When using this code, {{unansweredQuestions}} is still giving me the total number of questions until I get to the questions/index route when it resolves correctly.

Comment: It's likely you'll want to use the `afterModel` hook in the route.  It sounds like you want to resolve all of the questions and answers before the course route is displayed, is this true?

Comment: If the only way to get the array computed properties related to the question-answers relationship is to resolve all the questions and answers, then yes. I also don't want to do anything against the Ember way. Is this an acceptable way to go about it?

Answer (score 2):

Use `afterModel`.

You can force a relationship to resolve which will block the route from completing until the relationship has resolved.

#### Route

```
model: function(){
// assuming we return the course here and you want to resolve questions and answers
},
afterModel: function(model, transition){
  // assuming questions are async
  return model.get('questions').then(function(questions){
    return Ember.RSVP.all(questions.getEach('answers'));
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I edited my answer to show you the relevant code. My computed property still doesn't seem to be resolving in the course route.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I wasn't making the call to get all the questions from my backend in the Course Route.

> Course Route

In my course route model hook, I went from:

```
model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('course', params.course_id);
},
```

to:

```
model: function(params) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
        course: this.store.find('course', params.course_id),
        questions: this.store.find('question')
    });
},
```

and now my questions and associated answers exist in my store when I'm in my course route. Thanks to Kingpin2k for getting me looking in the right direction.